# Populating a hidden form field from a url parameter using javascript

Tags: javascript

Trying to take a parameter in the URL and make it the value for a hidden form field:

```
<form method="get" action="parameters.html">
  <input type="hidden" name="referredby" id="referredby" value="">
</form> 

<script language="JavaScript">
    function addComment()
    {
        var parameters = location.search.substring(1).split("&");

        var temp = parameters[0].split("=");
        r = decodeURI(temp[1]);

        document.getElementById('referredby').value = r;
    }
addComment();
</script>
```

Comment: The `addComment()` call needs to be inside the `<script>` tag.

Comment: Your function would probably be more robust if it used [`.searchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams) instead of manually deconstructing the queryString. For example, `const url = new URL(location.href); const referredby = url.searchParams.get('referredby')`